# Не работает ajax запрос на cordova ios

Tags: ajax, ios, cordova

Пример запроса

```
 $.ajax({
               url: 'http://reddit.com/.json',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function( data ) {
               alert( "SUCCESS:  " + data );
               },
               error: function( data ) {
               alert( "ERROR:  " + data );
               }
               });
```

Хотя разрешения в файле config.xml стоит

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Заголовок в файле index.html также прописан

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://reddit.com https://www.reddit.com">
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в заголовке

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```